# Haskell No instance for ... arising

Tags: haskell, types, numbers, typeclass

I'm trying to write a function that tests if the square root of a number is whole or not.
My function looks like this:

```
check :: [Int] -> [Int]
check xs = filter (\n -> n == round sqrt n) xs
```

And the error messages I'm receiving are these:

```
No instance for (Integral (Int -> Int))
(maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
arising from a use of "round"
In the second argument of "(==)", namely "round sqrt n"
 ...
No instance for (Floating a0) arising from a use of `sqrt'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Floating Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
In the first argument of `round', namely `sqrt'
```

Edit: I ended up rewriting the whole question, I hope thats not a problem!

Comment: You want `round (sqrt n)` and not `round sqrt n`. Also you need a fromIntegral on the righthand expression. So `check = filter (\n -> n == fromIntegral (round (sqrt n)))`

Comment: Aren't the function calls right-associative?
Also, I still get two error messages:
`No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of "round"`
`No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of "sqrt"`

Comment: Remove your `[Int] -> [Int]` type, you want `[Double] -> [Double]` for example. If you really want `Int` then you have to further change the definition. Function calls are left-associative.

Comment: Why do I have to change the definition?

Comment: Because `sqrt` has a `Floating` constraint. You could do `check = filter (\n -> n == round (sqrt (fromIntegral n)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found another solution by myself:

```
check :: [Int] -> [Int]
check xs = filter (\n -> (ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral n))) == (floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n)))) xs
```

This is the only one that doesn't throw compiler errors (in my case).

Answer (score 2):

it will work if you remove the left `fromIntegral`:

```
test n = n == fromIntegral (round n)
```

the reason is that as it is your `n` has to be `RealFrac` (`round`) and `Integral` (`fromIntegral`) but there is no type in the prelude which is both (neither `Integer` nor `Double` for example)

if you remove the left `fromIntegral` you only need `n` to have a type which is an instance of `RealFrac` - `Double` for example

the right side is like this:

```
RealFrac -round-> Integral -fromIntegral-> RealFrac
```

---

if you are in doubt you can always ask GHCi:

```
Prelude> :i RealFrac
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where
  properFraction :: Integral b => a -> (b, a)
  truncate :: Integral b => a -> b
  round :: Integral b => a -> b
  ceiling :: Integral b => a -> b
  floor :: Integral b => a -> b
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

as you can see this type-class gives you ways to *cut*-back numbers to `Integral` (ask for `Integral` to see what it's about - hint: think something like Integers)

you also see the *known* instances

if you see `RealFrac Int` it means it was looking to find a `RealFrac` instance-definition for `Int` (there is none)

Why there is an `Int` is another matter:

- either you ran into a technicality: GHCi default `n` to `Int` here - you probably ran into the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) - which should not happen like this with newer GHC versions but well ...
- or you use it in a context which constraints it to `Int` (which we do not see)

to be honest I'm not sure which it is here

Comment: It didn't work without the first fromIntegral either.

Edit: But does that mean fromIntegral is just something like a constraint for the following? I thought it was something like a converter function

Comment: Also Yes, its an Int because of the context ;)

Comment: well obviously it is rather useless with an `Int` in the first place (a `Int` is always *whole*) - but in this case it would be something like `test n = n == round (fromIntegral n)` - you use `fromIntegral` to get to some `RealFrac` and then you can use `round` to go back - but remember: this is practically useless

Comment: also: you should always add type-signatures if you ask a question here (and it is a good idea to do so in your code too)

Comment: Oh wow, with all these typeclasses I forgot what I going to do... I wanted to check if the square root of the number is whole or not.
I'll edit the context into my question.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
check :: [Int] -> [Int]
check xs = filter (\n -> fromIntegral n == round (sqrt (fromIntegral n))) xs
```

The error message is telling you the problem:

```
(maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
arising from a use of "round"
```

Because `round sqrt n` calls `round` with the arguments `sqrt` and `n`.

But that still doesn't do what you want. You need to `sqrt` the other side as well

```
check :: [Int] -> [Int]
check xs = filter (\n -> sqrt (fromIntegral n) == round (sqrt (fromIntegral n))) xs
```

Comment: Oh of course the other side too... Well im definitely too tired right now, so i will try this tomorrow, thank you very much!

Comment: still errors: `Ambiguous type variable "a0" in the constraints:
  (Floating a0)
    arising from a use of "sqrt"
  (Integral a0)
    arising from a use of "fromIntegral"
  (Num a0)
    arising from a use of "fromIntegral" `
Do you guys have a link or something where I can learn all these stuff about number typeclasses? I couldn't find anything newbie friendly and informative with google.